# How to configure AngularJS file in Struts.xml?

Tags: java, json, angularjs, struts2

I am developing a web application using Struts2. I am fetching records from a database and displaying it in `.json` format. But I want to display the details in a JSP page in tabular format. Whenever I am running the page on server individually, I am getting the results. But after configuring it in `struts.xml`, I am not getting it in tabular format.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
      "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
      "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
     <struts>
       <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
       <package name="helloworld" extends="json-default">

       <action name="jsondbsession" class="com.cisco.dbc.DbSessionService"
            method="getDbSessions">
            <result name="success">demo.jsp</result>
            <result name="error">sessionError.jsp</result>

       </action>

       </package>
       </struts>
```

As you can see in the `struts.xml` file, I have removed **`type="json"`** in action tag. Then the output is a table with no records.

But if I write **`type="json"`**, then I get the data in json format, not in tabular format.

```
    "sessionDetailsBeansList": [
{
"EVENT": "pmon timer",
"IDLE_MINS": 281,
"INST_ID": 1,
"LOGON": "17-APR-2015 11:18:21",
"MACHINE": "TKANTAPR-WS",
"MODULE": null,
"OSUSER": "SYSTEM",
"SERIAL": 1,
"SID": 87,
"SPID": "3296",
"SQL_HASH_VALUE": 0,
"STATUS": "ACTIVE",
"USERNAME": null
}"
```

this is my angularjs code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<style>
    tr {
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div align="center" data-ng-app="myApp" data-ng-controller="DbSessionServiceController"> 
<table border="1">
    <tr class="thead" style="font-size: large;text-align: center;">
        <td>INTANCE ID</td>
        <td>SID</td>
        <td>SERIAL</td>
        <td>USERNAME</td>
        <td>SPID</td>
        <td>OS USER</td>
        <td>STATUS</td>
        <td>MODULE</td>
        <td>MACHINE</td>
        <td>SQL HASH VALUE</td>
        <td>LOGON</td>
        <td>EVENT</td>
        <td>IDLE MINS</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-ng-repeat="x in names">
        <td>{{ x.INST_ID }}</td>
        <td>{{ x.SID }}</td>
        <td>{{ x.SERIAL }}</td>
        <td>{{ x.USERNAME }}</td>
        <td>{{ x.SPID }}</td>
        <td>{{ x.OSUSER }}</td>
        <td>{{ x.STATUS }}</td>
        <td>{{ x.MODULE }}</td>
        <td>{{ x.MACHINE }}</td>
        <td>{{ x.SQL_HASH_VALUE }}</td>
        <td>{{ x.LOGON }}</td>
        <td>{{ x.EVENT }}</td>
        <td>{{ x.IDLE_MINS }}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>  

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('DbSessionServiceController', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get("http://localhost:8088/dbcui/jsondbsession.action?InstanceName=LOCAL").
    success(function (response) {$scope.names = response.sessionDetailsBeansList;});
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The output should come in a tabular format. What am I missing here?

Comment: Of course you need to use `json` result type. What do you mean by - *then I get the data in json format* ?

Comment: what happens if you do a console.log($scope.names); after it success?

Comment: @AleksandrM I have written the output below. It should come in a tabular format.

Comment: In the typical struts2-angularjs application uses convention or rest plugin to invoke actions something similar like grails.

Comment: Where do you see this output? So you are thinking that your `ng-repeat` isn't working?

Comment: @AleksandrM I see this output in internal browser of eclipse. Yeah I think my ng-repeat isn't working.

Comment: Where exactly? Also try to display names with console.log like kamirru asked you.

Comment: `$scope.names = response.data;` ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no special Struts2 configuration necessary when using AngularJS.

For a good start with Struts2 and AngularJS I recommend to you try out the [Struts2 AngularJS Maven Archetype](http://struts.apache.org/docs/struts-2-maven-archetypes.html#Struts2MavenArchetypes-TheAngularJSArchetype%28struts2-archetype-angularjs%29) to step into this topic and how it should be configured.

```
mvn archetype:generate -B -DgroupId=com.mycompany.mysystem \
                            -DartifactId=myWebApp \
                            -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.struts \
                            -DarchetypeArtifactId=struts2-archetype-angularjs \
                            -DarchetypeVersion=<CURRENT_STRUTS_VERSION> \
                            -DremoteRepositories=http://struts.apache.org
```

This archetype generates you a initial project stack with a sample AngularJS configuration.